# Is the Wonder Woman theme original?

Tags: soundtrack, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, wonder-woman

After watching the new Wonder Woman [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q8fG0TtVAY) I noticed the prominent use of the 5-note (if I'm counting correctly) theme that's played at the end (starting at 2:05).    Yes there's a lot of reverb or some other accoustical effect here, but the core theme appears to be 5 notes.

I rewatched the Batman v. Superman UE on blu-ray and noted that the theme is played on multiple occassions, always tied to Wonder Woman being on screen.    My question is:  is this theme an original piece scored for BvS and reused in the Wonder Woman trailer, or is this taken from some prior music used in older media?   Perhaps the Linda Carter show, Justice League cartoons, or some other Wonder Woman piece?

Comment: It sounds _very_ familiar to me, I'm still trying to piece together where, but I think that arrangement is original, just similar to something else.

Comment: It is very similar to the Immigrant Song by Led Zeppelin

Comment: It is original as far as I can tell, however it seems to be at least somewhat inspired by "Immigrant Song" by Led Zeppelin as mentioned in one of the answers. I think when Dvaed listens to Immigrant Song (which totally rocks btw) he will know why it sounds a little familiar.

Comment: Doesn't seem particularly inspired by Immigrant Song, IMO.  The similarity is cursory and fleet, at most.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Composer [**Hans Zimmer**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001877/) says in [this video interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypoTnXt_k_Y&feature=youtu.be&t=59):

> ***It was really important for me to figure out how to find, like this
> banshee wail ... but it had to be feminine**.*
>
> ***After, you know, a hundred
> thousand experiments that all went wrong I suddently remembered this
> friend of mine, this cellist, [Tina Guo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tina_Guo)**, who, when you meet her, is very
> elegant, quite ... regal ... and then when she grabs her cello she
> becomes ... it's like a sword ... it just becomes ... she does become
> the banshee, she does become the Wonder Woman.*
>
> *Once I figured that
> out, you know, all of it is about casting and **these musicians we work
> with, we cast them as if they were actors ... I just had to find the
> right actress.** And suddenly it all sort of started to fall into place.*

He reiterates the same origin of the theme [this interview](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/One-Change-Wonder-Woman-Should-Make-From-Batman-v-Superman-According-Hans-Zimmer-121617.html):

> *One thing that has bugged me forever is that **our superhero movies are
> so masculine and male generated. I wanted Wonder Woman to be… I wanted
> the music to be full of more female… but you know, I wanted a banshee
> wail, like you’ve never heard before.***
>
> *So my friend [Tina Guo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tina_Guo), who’s an
> amazing electric cellist, basically typecast her, because whenever she
> picks up her cello that very nice, very sweet, very polite, young
> woman turns into a warrior princess in one go…*
>
> *There is a different
> sound you get from the drummers when we have [**Sheila E.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheila_E.) playing amongst
> them. It just gives you a different sound. It gives you just as much
> ferocity, but it’s a different type, so we were looking at things like
> that.*

Comment: So...the actual resumé from those quotes would be...? Is it original or is it taken from prior music?

Answer (score 0):

This theme does seem really similar to the cartoon X-men theme with a middle eastern twist. Here's the links:

X-MEN theme:

Random Middle Eastern cello music:

And it also does sound similar to Led Zeppelin's Inmigrant song because of the mixture of the vocal line with the guitar effect:

Hope it helps, it had been bugging me for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it sounds familiar is because if, like me, you grew up watching the X-Men cartoon, then listen to that theme and there is definite similarity

Comment: Kindly elaborate bit more else it look like comment  rather than answer

Answer (score -2):

I was wondering the same thing. I know I heard it before and finally I got it.

The new wonder woman song is a tweaked version of the get smart theme song from the tv show. Check it out and you will see I am right.